# how provide multiple service as object in nestjs module

Tags: nestjs

I am working on a payment module in Nestjs, this module has multiple payment gateways, I made a spread module for each gateway this is my current folder structure

```
payments
 ┣ gateways
 ┃ ┣ modules
 ┃ ┃ ┣ first-gateway
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ first-gateway.module.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ first-gateway.service.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ second-gateway
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ second-gateway.module.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ second-gateway.service.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index.ts
 ┃ ┣ abstarct.gateway.service.ts
 ┃ ┗ gateways.module.ts
 ┣ payments.controller.spec.ts
 ┣ payments.controller.ts
 ┣ payments.module.ts
 ┣ payments.service.spec.ts
 ┗ payments.service.ts
```

this is an abstract gateway module that each gateway should extend from it :

```
//abstarct.gateway.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export abstract class GatewayService {
  abstract readonly name: string;
  abstract createPayment<T>(): Promise<T>;
  abstract verifyPayment<T>(): Promise<T>;
}
```

and this is one of my gateways for example :

```
//first-gateway.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GatewayService } from '../../abstarct.gateway.service';

@Injectable()
export class FirstGateWayService extends GatewayService {
  readonly name: string = 'first';
  createPayment<T>(): Promise<T> {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
  verifyPayment<T>(): Promise<T> {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
}
```

```
//first-gateway.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FirstGateWayService } from './first-gateway.service';

@Module({
  providers: [FirstGateWayService],
  exports: [FirstGateWayService],
})
export class FirstGatewayModule {}
```

and in index.ts i export those modules :

```
export * from './first-gateway/first-gateway.module';
export * from './second-gateway/second-gateway.module';
```

now the question is how can I make one object that gives me access to different gateways in gateways.module with type safety something like this :

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as Gateways from './modules/index';

@Module({
  imports: [Gateways.FirstGatewayModule, Gateways.SecondGatewayModule],
  providers: [
    /* how make object te get access to all gateways here
      some thing like this:
      {
        provide: 'Gateways',
        useValue: {first: FirstGateWayService, second: SecondGateWayService}
      }
    */
  ],
})
export class GatewaysModule {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a factory and inject the two (or more) services into the factory and have it return the object with the instances you want.

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as Gateways from './modules/index';

@Module({
  imports: [Gateways.FirstGatewayModule, Gateways.SecondGatewayModule],
  providers: [
    /* how make object the get access to all gateways here
      some thing like this:*/
      {
        provide: 'Gateways',
        useFactory: (firstGatewayService, secondGatewayService) => ({
          first: firstGatewayService,
          second: secondGatewayService
        }),
        inject: [FirstGateWayService, SecondGateWayService],
      }
  ],
})
export class GatewaysModule {}
```